# Metrics misreporting for certain spring kafka config settings

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have a spring kafka consumer that receives batches and runs a loop to process each record in the batch. Also have a counter in the loop that increments each time we process a record.

I recently added `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` config options to my kafka consumer factory to pull in larger batches for efficiency and log related cost savings. Since then, my record counter is reporting lower numbers. However, another counter that increments per batch with the batch size does not report lower values with this change.

Here is a sample code for what I have:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${topicNames}'.split(',')}")
public void consume(@Payload List<String> messages, 
                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment ack) {

    counter1.increment(messages.size());

    for (String message : messages) {

        counter2.increment();

        // process message
    }
    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

`topicNames` is two comma separated topics that this listener is consuming from.
`concurrency` is 5 and there are 100 partitions on one topic and 30 on the other.

`counter2` reports significantly lower record numbers than `counter1`. I expect to see *some* difference between the two as a function of how they're incremented, but over longer periods of time, it shouldn't be significant.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Makes no sense, unless the counters are not thread-safe. What type are `counter1` and `counter2`? You should be using something thread-safe like `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Yeah. The counters are `io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter`. From my search so far, micrometer counters are thread-safe.

Comment: Counter is an interface, which implementation? This can’t have anything to do with Spring, or Kakfa; you are incrementing both counters outside of their scope. Suggest you reproduce independent of those projects.

Comment: My bad. It's using the Statsd implementation. I'm only seeing the issue on using the `fetch.min.bytes` config for my kafka consumer, which is why it seems related.

Comment: That will have no difference, you are incrementing both counters in the same method. It matters not how long it took to poll the consumer to receive the list of records.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue completely but you are using an inefficient and expensive protocol (StatsD). When you increment a Counter, a network call will go out to your StatsD backend (there is some buffering).  If your  StatsD backend is busy or there are network hiccups, those datapoints will be dropped. If you use UDP on top of this, it is even worse. Try to look at the `/actuator/metrics` endpoint to see if that matches with StatsD (or use a different protocol).